# Using PhoneGap, can't load local .html file using Ajax on Android only

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

I'm using PhoneGap (latest), Jquery 1.7.  I'm having troubles getting some html loaded via AJAX into a div.  My problem is simple, I have an index.html file in the www/ directory.  And a js file that does this:

```
$.ajax({
 type:"GET",
 timeout:10000,
 dataType: "html",
 async: false,
 cache: false,
 url: "file:///android_asset/www/_liqui-cult.html",
 success: function(data) {
  $('#data_details .description').html(data); // never runs
 },
 error: function(xhr,msg){
   alert(xhr.status + ", " + msg);
   if(xhr.status == 0 || xhr.status == "0"){
    alert(xhr.responseText); // always blank, if runs
   }
 }
});
```

Having spent the day Googling this error, I've tried numerous things, but the AJAX call never succeeds.  I've tried changing the url to simply, `_liqui-cult.html` (without the file:// -based url).  I've also tried `/_liqui-cult.html`.

I started out trying with the JQuery `$.load`, and that wasn't working, so I switched to the more verbose `$.ajax` call.

No matter what I do, I either get a 404 as the status, or, if I change the url to `http://_liqui-cult.html`, I get a status of 0, but nothing in the responseText.

So, I took JQuery out of the equation, and tried a simple XMLHttpRequest, as so:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && (xmlhttp.status==200 || xmlhttp.status==0))
  {
    $('#data_details .description').html(xmlhttp.responseText);
    $.mobile.changePage('#screen_detail');
  }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","_liqui-cult.html", true);
xmlhttp.send(null);
```

Again, I've tried every conceivable url pattern to map to the html file.  And still, the best I can get is xmlhttp.responseText is blank.

So how about cross-origin issues?  Here is what I've tried:
    `<access origin=".*"/>`
    `<access origin="file://*"/>`
    `<access origin="*"/>`

Again, I've tried all ways of mapping to the html file, with those different access origin settings, and I still cannot load the html file.

Any ideas?

Comment: By the way, I am targeting Android 3, API Level 11.  The same code works fine in iOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the name of the html file that gets AJAX-loaded from "_liqui-cult.html" to the same name without the underscore "liqui-cult.html" fixed the problem.

Comment: Wow, this saved my life. Thanks!!

Comment: I'm confused; why would this fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Seems something else is wrong in your project. The following gist have some of the files from my test application and it works without any issue in Android.

https://gist.github.com/2873186

Comment: Thank you very much for looking into it.  It turns out the issue was with the underscore in the name of the AJAX'ed file.  Changing the name to "liqui-cult.html" fixed the problem.