# Phonegap CORS issue

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, cors

I am trying to open and read an XML file from Phonegap but having this CORS error. How can I resolve this?

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file://localhost/../data/file.xml. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

The caller code is:

```
var request = $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "data/file.xml",
    async: false,
    dataType: "xml"
  });
```

I also have this snippet in my code due to the explanation [here](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/phonegap.html):

```
$(document).on( "mobileinit", function() {

           $.support.cors = true;
           $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;

           });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to mod your phonegap settings to allow access to localhost

Theres a few files to look at so see this [gist](https://gist.github.com/2873186) and other [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889278/using-phonegap-cant-load-local-html-file-using-ajax-on-android-only) post.

Note those examples are for Android; with iPhone its the same issue, just different files.

Comment: It doesn't help unfortunately.